# Consume Secure Azure API from SharePoint online

Tags: azure, authentication, sharepoint-online, azure-api-apps, adal.js

I have developed Azure API app with  authentication on feature, log in with Azure Active Directory, I need to consume this API from SharePoint online ,  I
I need to authenticate and consume the azure API, no signin-prompt, every thing should be handled in the script
need to use ADAL.js to authenticate secure API ,I cannot find any good reference about the JavaScript code, I was wondering if anyone have a good reference how the JavaScript code should look like?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you fixed this issue now?

Comment: Yes , it works now , I posted my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to call the azure hosted API from SharePoint online using JavaScript and ADAL.js library, no signing-prompt, everything should be handled in the script using ADAL.js to authenticate secure API

**Create and Configure API**

1. Create azure API
2. Publish your azure API in azure
3. Browse to azure portal, select your API application , select **Authentication/Authorizations**

   - Set the App Service **Authentication: On**
   - Action to take when request us not authenticated: **Log in with Azure dictionary**
   - Authentication providers: **Express**
     [image]
4. Now the API is protected with Azure AD, if you navigate your API via browser you will be prompted for login
5. When we set authentication in Express mode, the app will be created automatically in Azure Active directory, you can see the name under Azure AD app
6. Navigate to Azure management portal, click on **active directory** in left navigation,

[image]

7. Click on the Directory which will be federated to your office 365 (or any source you want to call azure API which uses the same azure active directory as your configured for you API authentication)
8. Click on the Application, and you will find you AD app in the list which has been created with Express method as we discussed om step nr.3
9. Now we need to create new app in AAD which will be our communication channel from office 365 to Azure API, Click on ADD on footer
10. Enter name and select “WEB APPLICATION AND/OR WEB AP” option
11. For **Sign in URL** enter your SharePoint online Url which you are planning to call Azure API from
12. For **APP ID UR**L, enter unique Url, this will be used as a unique logical identifier for your app.
13. After the app created, click on Configure, copy the **Client ID** which will be used later­­
14. Under **Permission to other applications**, Click “**Add Application**”, on the next page select “**All App**s” and select you Azure API app which you double checked in step nr.8, and confirm
15. You will be redirected back to Configure page, Under **Permission to other applications**, now you see your azure API app is listed here, click on **delegated permission**, select the access to app
16. At the bottom of the page, click **Manage manifest > Download manifes**t.
17. Download the file to a location where you can edit it.
18. In the downloaded manifest file, search for the **oauth2AllowImplicitFlow** property. Change the value of this property from **false** to **true**, and then save the file.
19. Click **Manage manifest > Upload manifest**, and upload the file that you updated in the preceding step.
20. Azure management portal, select setting and copy your AAD subscription ID for related AAD
    [image]

**Call Azure API from SharePoint Online**

Once the above steps have been done, you can call azure API from sharePoint online  which is using same Active directory above

21. Edit the page and add Script Editor web part
22. Add following script 
    · subscriptionId,  see step nr.20
    · clientId  see step nr.13

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.13/js/adal.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function CallAzureAPI() {
    "use strict";
  
    var subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    var clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
    window.config = {
        subscriptionId: subscriptionId,                 
        clientId: clientId,     
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        endpoints: {
            AzureApiUri: 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net'
        }, 
         cacheLocation: 'localStorage' 
    };
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);    
    var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);
    authContext.handleWindowCallback();    
    if (isCallback && !authContext.getLoginError()) {
        window.location = authContext._getItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST);
    }    
    // If not logged in force login
    var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
    if (user) {
        // Logged in already
        console.log(user);
    } 
    else {
        
        authContext.login();
    }    
    // Acquire token for Files resource.
    authContext.acquireToken(config.endpoints. AzureApiUri, function (error, token) {
        // Handle ADAL Errors.
        if (error || !token) {
            console.log('ADAL error occurred: ' + error);
            return;
        }
        var ApiUri = "https://xxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Get";

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: ApiUri,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log('Successfully called API.');
            console.log(response);
            
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log('Calling API failed.');
           
        });
    });
}
</script>
<input type='button' value='Call Azure API' onclick=" CallAzureAPI ();"/>
```

This solution works though after some time ( later I found out when AAD cookie is expired ) we get this error "**Token renewal operation failed due to timeout** ",

I did some research and I found out he getCachedUser or getUser methods look into the browser storage for id_token and returns a non-null user if there is a token inside the cache. It does not look into the token expiration time though.
What's happening here is since localStorage is used, tokens are preserved in the cache when one re-opens the browser (and hence getCachedUser returns a non-null object) but the AAD cookie is expired (unless user checked the keep me signed in checkbox when logging in). Since the cookie is expired, acquire token call fails with the "login required" error.

so as workaround I checked , **keep me signed in** checkbox when logging in and it works .

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to call the web API which protected by Azure AD from the SharePoint online using the JavaScript, however it is very complex.

Here are the steps for your reference:

1. Developing the web API which protected by Azure AD
2. register an native app on the same tenant
3. enable the **implicit flow** for the native app
4. grant the native app to access the web API from Azure portal
5. using the [admin_consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-integrating-applications) for the native app to grant permission fo the organization
6. developing a web page in web API project for the redrect page for the OAuth 2.0 request
7. write the code in the web page using windows.postMessage to post the token to the parent page

   ```
   $().ready(function () {
       if (window.parent != null) {
           // get the token from URL here
           var token = "123";
           console.log(window.location);
           window.parent.postMessage(token, "*");
       }

   })
   ```
8. In SharePoint online page, using iframe to send the implict flow like code below

```html
<iframe id="iframe_id" src="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenanit}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={clientId}&resource={webApiAppIdUri}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&prompt=none"></iframe>
<script>
        var token = "";
        window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

        function receiveMessage(event) {
            token=event.data;
            console.log(event.data);
        }
      
</script>
```

Here is a figure to help understanding the progress:
[image]